# Member functions

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, member-functions

I am getting an error at the line "void operation" when I compile, because I havent defined Gate_ptr yet. I thought of exchanging the "Gate_ptr" with just "Gate*" instead in the function def. However, is there a way to maintain my current style?

```
  class Gate
    {
        public:
                Gate();
          void operation(Gate_ptr &gate_tail, string type, int input1, int input2=NULL);

        private:
                int cnt2;
                int input_val1, input_val2;
                int output, gate_number;
                int input_source1, input_source2;
                int fanout[8];
                Gate* g_next;
                string type;
};
typedef Gate* Gate_ptr;
```

Comment: No, the compiler has to know about the types before it can compile the code. It doesn't read ahead. Why not just declare the types first?

Comment: `int input=NULL` (At the parameter list of `operation` method) is just wierd (though legal). Maybe `int* input=NULL` or `int input=0` ?

Comment: Well, thats for when I am access the function,and I decide not to pass a parameter into "input2"

Comment: `NULL` is defined as 0, but when you need to assign an integer variable to 0, you should use the `0` not the `NULL`. `NULL` should be used for pointers. Also in some platforms/compilers `NULL` may have `void*` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer this order:

```
 //forward decleration
class Gate;

//typedef based on forward dec.
typedef Gate* Gate_ptr; 

//class definition
class Gate
{
   public:
//...
};
```

Comment: Yes, as Luchian Grigore points out in his answer, `class Gate;` is a forward declaration. Quite a useful feature when you have two headers including each other.

Answer (score 4):

Forwared declare, do the typedef, then define the class:

```
class Gate;
typedef Gate* Gate_ptr;

class Gate
{
    public:
            Gate();
            void operation(Gate_ptr &gate_tail, string type, int input1, int input2=NULL);

    private:
            int cnt2;
            int input_val1, input_val2;
            int output, gate_number;
            int input_source1, input_source2;
            int fanout[8];
            Gate* g_next;
            string type;
};
```